# How to initilaze react-native on the view of window manager from android

Tags: react-native

I'm searching the way to implement running react-native application on both of activity and service in single package.

Running RN app on activity is usual, but can't find the right way to execute another react-native application on the service. The latter app should be run on the foreground service and view on the window manager.

My code roughly looks like:

```
// ReactNativeWindowService.kt
fun startNewReactWindow(
        reactContext: ReactContext,
        jsMainModuleName: String?,
        bundleAssetName: String?,
        module: String
) {
    Toast.makeText(reactContext, "START()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val headLayout = createHeadLayout(reactContext)
    headsManager.addLayout(headLayout)

    launch(UI) {
        reactInstanceManager = createReactInstanceManager(reactContext, jsMainModuleName, bundleAssetName)
        reactRootView = ReactRootView(reactContext)
        reactRootView?.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, module, null)

        headsManager.addHeadView(bubbleLayout.apply { addView(reactRootView) })
    }
}
```

But, this code produce:

```
07-10 01:05:07.662 26269-26380/Sample E/ReactNativeJS: Error while starting app: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeReactModule.startApp')
07-10 01:05:07.674 26269-26380/Sample I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "index" with appParams: {"rootTag":21}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
07-10 01:05:07.674 26269-26380/Sample E/ReactNativeJS: Application index has not been registered.

Hint: This error often happens when you're running the packager (local dev server) from a wrong folder. For example you have multiple apps and the packager is still running for the app you were working on before.
If this is the case, simply kill the old packager instance (e.g. close the packager terminal window) and start the packager in the correct app folder (e.g. cd into app folder and run 'npm start').

This error can also happen due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
```

I'm sure that code passed right parameters such as jsMainModuleName to create ReactInstanceManager. (I got same parameters as activity's params)

What do I miss in my code? or any other reference/docs/advice that would be helpful to me. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your file MainAcitivity.java has a function

```
protected String getMainComponentName() {
   return "your file name for example abc";
}
```

But in your index.android.js file you register other component

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('123', () => 143);
```

Where it must be like this e.g.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('abc', () => abc);
```

Try to fix it.